# How to add jitter to avoid overplot in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there any way I can add jitter to the dot on the plot to avoid overplot?
X axis is "categorical" value and "y axis" is "numeric" value. 
with codes given below, I could plot on X/Y but some observations are overlapped.

thanks,

Part of my code is

```
var xValue = function(d) { return d[xVar];}, // data -> value
    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
               .rangeRoundBands([0,width],1),
      xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));},
     xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

var yValue = function(d) { return d[yVar];}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
      yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
     yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", radius)
  .attr("cx", xMap)
  .attr("cy", yMap)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add jitter to all x values as below.
xMap = function(d) { return (xScale(xValue(d)) + Math.random()*10);}, 
this will help to avoid overplot.